# the option to delete plugins is not there, I can't download plugins either

Tags: plugins

I'm still learning how to build a website and I want to start over, I have done several times, but now I don't have the option to delete the plugins, an when I try to install a new theme it say

Comment: Do you have admin rights? Do you have a network install?

Comment: maybe check your file permissions

Comment: Is it possible that you have somewhere (*in `wp-config.php` or `functions.php`*) a code with `DISALLOW_FILE_MODS` or `DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT`? If so then lays your answer there, else see comments above.